# Multipart E-mail Using MailMessage

Tags: c#, email, mime-types, content-type

I have an E-mail I want to send from C# which has a vCalendar and an HTML body parts.

I created a `MailMessage`, and set 2 alternate views:

```
AlternateView avCal  = new AlternateView("VCALENDAR:...", null, "text/calendar");
AlternateView avHtml = new AlternateView("<p>some html</p>", null, "text/html");

mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
mailMessage.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);
```

This gives me a message with a `Content-Type` of `multipart/alternative`.

This will show both the calendar appointment and HTML part on my webmail but not Outlook.

How can I show two different parts like this with different content types? What I'm looking for is more like a `Content-Type: multipart/mixed` where both "Alternate Views" show up.

**EDIT**

When I use @Chris Haas's method, I get close but the markup is not rendered. It seems to be ignoring `MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true`

[image: html not showing up]

not really sure how to view it raw in outlook but just the headers...

```
Return-Path: <*****@****.com>
X-Footer: ZWJyaWRnZS5jb20=
Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1])
    by mail.foo.com
    for *****@****.com;
    Wed, 2 Jan 2013 17:20:14 -0500
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "George Washington" <*****@****.com>
To: "George Washington" <*****@****.com>
Date: 2 Jan 2013 17:29:14 -0500
Subject: To-Do: test test - test
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
boundary=--boundary_0_4fbc08b4-2198-45b1-bf2e-9659179aad84
```

Comment: I have this issue, but ONLY when the message is sent to an outlook.com address. In Outlook/Mac, the message displays the content ofthe .ics as text, the HTML text is missing, and the .ics file is present. If the recipient is not someone@outlook.com, then Outlook/Mac renders the message perfectly, with the HTML and the .ics attachment intact. This issue appears to have everything to do with manipulation of the content by Outlook.com, possibly a result of safelinks and spam filtering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try sending the VCALENDAR as an `Attachment` with the `Inline` attribute set to `true`:

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("...", "...", "Subject here", "Body here")) //Pick whatever constructor you want
{
    using (Attachment a = new Attachment("c:\\test.ics", "text/calendar")) //Either load from disk or use a MemoryStream bound to the bytes of a String
    {
        a.Name = "meeting.ics";                         //Filename, possibly not required
        a.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;             //Mark as inline
        mm.Attachments.Add(a);                          //Add it to the message
        using (SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient("..."))    //Send using normal
        {
            s.Send(mm);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Okay, I've updated the code to not rely on a file, so that we're using the exact same ICS file. Update the strings at the top and the `SmtpClient` if needed but otherwise leave the code exactly as is. The ICS is from the middle of [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/02/26/building-vcalendar-and-ical-is-not-supported-by-ms.aspx).

```
  String mailFrom = "xyz@example.com";
  String mailTo = "xyz@example.com";
  String mailSubject = "This is a test";
  String mailBody = "<p><strong>Hello</strong> world</p>";
  String smtpServer = "mail.example.com";

  using (var mm = new MailMessage()) //Pick whatever constructor you want
  {
      mm.To.Add(mailFrom);
      mm.From = new MailAddress(mailTo);
      mm.Subject = mailSubject;
      mm.Body = mailBody;
      mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
      String t = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n" +
                 "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n" +
                 "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n" +
                 "DTSTAMP:20080325T202857Z\r\n" +
                 "DTSTART:20080325T200000Z\r\n" +
                 "DTEND:20080325T220000Z\r\n" +
                 "SUMMARY:Test meeting request\r\n" +
                 "UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000B2BB07349575C80100000000000000001000000019BF8D0149C50643A81325C54140C093\r\n" +
                 "ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=\"Dan\":MAIL\r\n" +
                 " TO:myuser@mydom.com\r\n" +
                 "ORGANIZER;CN=\"Administrator\":MAILTO:administrator@mydom.com\r\n" +
                 "LOCATION: Here\r\n" +
                 "DESCRIPTION:Test Request\r\n" +
                 "SEQUENCE:0\r\n" +
                 "PRIORITY:5\r\n" +
                 "CLASS:\r\n" +
                 "CREATED:20080321T190958Z\r\n" +
                 "STATUS:CONFIRMED\r\n" +
                 "TRANSP:OPAQUE\r\n" +
                 "END:VEVENT\r\n" +
                 "END:VCALENDAR";
      Byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(t);
      using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
      {
          using (var a = new Attachment(ms, "meeting.ics", "text/calendar")) //Either load from disk or use a MemoryStream bound to the bytes of a String
          {
              a.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;             //Mark as inline
              mm.Attachments.Add(a);                          //Add it to the message
              using (SmtpClient s = new SmtpClient(smtpServer))    //Send using normal
              {
                  s.Send(mm);
              }
          }
      }

  }
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this does not solve the problem either. It shows the calendar but not the HTML body.

Comment: The `Attachment` should be added to the `MailMessage` but it really shouldn't matter "where" you put it. Do you have a requirement to use `AlternateViews`? The test I just did with the exact above code gave me a single email email in Outlook with a Calendar on the top and the text on the bottom. What do you get? My ICS file is the one from the middle of this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/02/26/building-vcalendar-and-ical-is-not-supported-by-ms.aspx

Comment: No AlternateView requirement.. getting closer with this method... though it is ignoring `IsBodyHtml = true`. I have editted the question with a screen of the result.

Comment: Sorry Tom, but whenever I run the code above exactly I get the dual window with HTML in tact. Are you sure you're running the above exactly without changes (SMTP variable aside of course)?

Comment: Ok, I did what you suggested and tried your calendar code above exactly. It made me realize the text in my screenshot is NOT what i put in `message.Body` but rather the DESCRIPTION field of the vcalendar.. wish I could see exactly whats sent to outlook from `SmtpClient`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to send your vCalendear (*.vcs) or iCalendar (*.ics) file as an attachment for Outlook to know what to do with it.

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287625
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2008/02/26/building-vcalendar-and-ical-is-not-supported-by-ms.aspx

The recipient will then need to open the email in Outlook and double-click the attachment to import it into the Outlook/Exchange calendar.

Comment: The above code will show the vCalendar just fine inline in the email. It does not show the html part however.

Comment: Update: Outlook (2007+) does not require the ics attachment anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; I could not get the invite to display the HTML without displaying the tags. I was able to solve the issue with something similiar to (variable f contains all the "BEGIN:VCALENDAR" stuff):

```
System.Net.Mime.ContentType calendarType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
AlternateView ICSview = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(f.ToString(), calendarType);
AlternateView HTMLV = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"));
MailMessage email = new MailMessage("from@example.com", "to@example.com", "subject", "body");
email.AlternateViews.Add(ICSview);
email.AlternateViews.Add(HTMLV);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Send(email);
```

I am sure the code could be tidied...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

Try adding two AlternateViews to MailMessage, one with content type text/calendar, with ics file, one with content type text/html, with email body.

Worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

None of these suggestions works for me.

Closest I've got, so far, is to attach a MemoryStream with "text/calendar" as the MIME type.
However, GMail does not recognize this file in the sense that it does not Display the summary from the .ICS file, neither does it allow me to 'Add to Calendar'.

However, when I forward the exact same email to myself (or others) on GMail, GMail DOES display the .ICS content. I am going crazy here trying to test different solutions.